# React-native cannot open ios simulator debug menu

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have a react-native project that I develop with an ios simulator (iPhone 8 mostly). I can't seem to open the debug menu with the regular command ⌘ + D.

I recently started applying pods as a way of integrating dependencies in my project, as I needed a specific library that requires it. After that change, I've no longer been able to open the debug menu (nor refresh the simulator app) with controls such as ⌘ + D and ⌘ + R. I've also tried to open those from the simulator top menu, with no luck. Shake gesture does not work either, no luck there.

The way Im running my app is as follows:

```
ENVFILE=.env.ios-development react-native run-ios --simulator 'iPhone 8'
```

I think it should resolve to debug mode and not release mode? Because one thing that could explain why the debug menu won't open is that the application is in release mode, where debug menu is not supported. But this shouldn't be the case because I just run it with the basic `react-native run-ios` command. How could I 100% be sure that it is not in release mode? I could open an alert from the app to test it (since console.log won't show because can't get to the debug menu). Also once I start the app it shows this in terminal:

> info Building using "xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyApp -destination id=356D169E-E11E-44B2-8AEF-015D0F24A203 -derivedDataPath build/MyApp"

And that -configuration flag with a value Debug would indicate that it's not in release mode.

My Podfile looks following:

```
project 'MyApp.xcworkspace'

# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# Allowed sources
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'myapp' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for myapp

  # Point to the installed version
  pod 'RNDateTimePicker', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/datetimepicker/RNDateTimePicker.podspec'

  # React/React-Native specific pods
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'CxxBridge',      # Include this for RN >= 0.47
    'DevSupport',     # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket',   # Needed for debugging
  ]

  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  # Third party deps podspec link
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  target 'myapp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'myappTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Could it be that the DevSupport module that enables the in-app debug menu is not properly installed? I mean this one:

```
'DevSupport',     # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
```

I've tried many answers from similar questions without success.

My react-native version is: 0.59.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix this by removing the `use_frameworks!` line from my Podfile. I guess Im lucky for not using any dynamic frameworks in my app, so was able to fix it with this solution. But I understand this is not optimal. So if someone figures a better alternative I might accept it instead.